# The [overflow] tag is overflowing with uses

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

The [overflow](/questions/tagged/overflow) tag is meant to be the CSS `overflow` property. However, the word "overflow" itself is extremely ambiguous and used in a zillion different ways, even the name of this site.

A [css-overflow](/questions/tagged/css-overflow) tag already exists. The [overflow](/questions/tagged/overflow) tag needs to be cleaned up and merged into that one. There are [about 800 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overflow+-css) tagged with [overflow](/questions/tagged/overflow) that are not also tagged with [css](/questions/tagged/css).

Comment: Jeez.  It might be easier to find all the *non*-CSS questions there and retag as appropriate.

Comment: @Charles: Yes, that's why I linked to that search. Retagging the non-CSS ones then doing a mass merge to [tag:css-overflow] seemed more logical.

Comment: Oh, hah!  I missed the negative there and was going off the main list's Related Tags.

Comment: Hey it was working just fine until it got 255 questions...